# Chef - How to create a template that contains a bcrypt hash without breaking the update of the resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I have this in one of my resources:

```
service 'my_service' do
  ...
end

template config_file do
  source new_resource.template_file
  variables({
    config: node[:a][:b][:c][:configs][new_resource.name]
  })

  notifies :restart, "service[my_service]"
end
```

The problem arises when one of my templates contains things such as a bcrypt password:

```
...
passhash = <%=
 require 'bcrypt'
 ::BCrypt::Password::create(@config[:password]) 
%>
```

This will cause the template resource to update, which in turn restarts my service at every chef run.

Do you have any good idea how to prevent generating a different hash at every run?

Generating the hash outside in the recipe and saving it in a normal attribute seems dirty...

Comment: I'm no Chef-savvy, but bcrypt expects plaintext password and salt. Also, given identical input, it should produce identical output. Is there any way to supply salt to `::BCrypt::Password::create`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The salt does not seem like a set of random numbers, but it is generated in a special way, in some C extension. Theoretically the salt generator *could* be supplied with the same set of random stream, but that's not exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little with the [code](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb#L46) of the BCrypt module and using a salt derived from `node['hostname']` to give different salt per machine while still giving a coherent salt on each run this should work :

```
passhash = <%=
 require 'bcrypt'
 salt="$2a$05$Whatever_you_want#{node['hostname'].hash.to_s}"
 ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(@config[:password],salt) 
%>
```

Example with dummy data in irb:

```
require 'bcrypt'
irb(main):067:0> salt="$2a$05$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
=> "$2a$05$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
irb(main):068:0> BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("toto",salt)
=> "$2a$05$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuuysiG0IbQUOykz7YKwKH2q3gpjfBWJZG"
irb(main):069:0> BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("toto",salt)
=> "$2a$05$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuuysiG0IbQUOykz7YKwKH2q3gpjfBWJZG"
```

Note the salt will be truncated, the part after the last $ has to be longer than 22 chars. [Validation code is here](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/engine.rb#L80-L82)

The start of the salt is as the entry in `/etc/shadow`, crypt method (`2a` for bcrypt), the second part is the number of round of keying according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)), next is the salt itself followed by the password hash.

Comment: The BCrypt hash seems to be generated with multiple iteration. Do we know that this is at least as secure as the original salt generaion?

Comment: That's the second part of the salt, with 05 it is the default value, you can use 10 to harden it. (To be tested)

Comment: @ÁkosVandra The underlying method is still bcrypt, you may argue it is less hard because the salt if guessable, but when you access a shadow it is the same thing. The number of iterations is the second parameter (between the second and third `$` range from 0 to 30, with a min implementation dependant) used by the raw blowfish crypt function [here](https://github.com/rg3/bcrypt/blob/master/crypt_blowfish/crypt_blowfish.c#L688) to determine the number of iteration to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but wound up caching the value in the chef file cache. Should probably refactor the code into a helper

```
        "<%= @config[:auth][:username] %>": "<%=
            require 'bcrypt'

            hash_cache_file = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'pass_hash.bcrypt')

            oldhash = ::BCrypt::Password.new(File.read(hash_cache_file).strip) if File.exist?(hash_cache_file)

            if oldhash == @config[:auth][:password]
                oldhash
            else
                ::BCrypt::Password::create(@config[:auth][:password]).tap do |newhash|
                    File.open(hash_cache_file, 'w') { |file| file.write(newhash) }
                end
            end
        %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that bcrypt is gone on chef 12.

```html
opt/chef/embedded/bin/irb 
irb(main):001:0> require 'bcrypt'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt
 from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from (irb):1
 from /opt/chef/embedded/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
  
  
ls lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/
addressable-2.4.0        hashie-3.5.3                 net-telnet-0.1.1            rspec-its-1.2.0
appbundler-0.10.0        highline-1.7.8               nokogiri-1.7.0.1            rspec_junit_formatter-0.2.3
ast-2.3.0                iniparse-1.4.2               ohai-8.23.0                 rspec-mocks-3.5.0
binding_of_caller-0.7.2  ipaddress-0.8.3              parser-2.4.0.0              rspec-support-3.5.0
builder-3.2.3            json-2.0.3                   plist-3.2.0                 rubocop-0.47.1
bundler-1.12.5           libyajl2-1.2.0               power_assert-0.2.6          rubygems-update-2.6.10
byebug-9.0.6             method_source-0.8.2          powerpack-0.1.1             ruby-prof-0.16.2
chef-12.19.36            mini_portile2-2.1.0          proxifier-1.0.3             ruby-progressbar-1.8.1
chef-config-12.19.36     minitest-5.8.3               pry-0.10.4                  ruby-shadow-2.5.0
cheffish-4.1.1           mixlib-archive-0.4.1         pry-byebug-3.4.2            serverspec-2.38.0
chefstyle-0.5.0          mixlib-authentication-1.4.1  pry-remote-0.1.8            sfl-2.3
chef-zero-5.3.0          mixlib-cli-1.7.0             pry-stack_explorer-0.4.9.2  simplecov-0.13.0
coderay-1.1.1            mixlib-config-2.2.4          rack-2.0.1                  simplecov-html-0.10.0
debug_inspector-0.0.2    mixlib-log-1.7.1             rainbow-2.2.1               slop-3.6.0
did_you_mean-1.0.0       mixlib-shellout-2.2.7        rake-10.4.2                 specinfra-2.66.9
diff-lcs-1.3             multi_json-1.12.1            rake-11.3.0                 syslog-logger-1.6.8
docile-1.1.5             net-scp-1.2.1                rb-readline-0.5.4           systemu-2.6.5
erubis-2.7.0             net-sftp-2.1.2               rdoc-4.2.1                  test-unit-3.1.5
ffi-1.9.17               net-ssh-4.0.1                rspec-3.5.0                 unicode-display_width-1.1.3
ffi-yajl-2.3.0           net-ssh-gateway-1.3.0        rspec-core-3.5.4            uuidtools-2.1.5
fuzzyurl-0.9.0           net-ssh-multi-1.2.1          rspec-expectations-3.5.0    wmi-lite-1.0.0
```

Comment: You can always add it as a chef_gem